# A Scala script for beautify scientific notation strings from Excel

Tags: scala, formatting, floating-point

Excel renders scientific notation in the engineering fashion, e.g. “4.2E-5”. That’s OK, but when you are writing a scientific paper, it’s likely that you want it to look like this: “4.2×10⁻⁵”.

I have come up with a Scala script that does the job perfectly well:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit
import java.awt.datatransfer.{StringSelection, DataFlavor}

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 13/10/15.
 */
object Scientific {
  val superscriptMap = {
    var tmp = collection.mutable.Map(
      '0' -> '\u2070',
      '1' -> '\u00b9',
      '2' -> '\u00b2',
      '3' -> '\u00b3'
    )
    val x = ('4' to '9').zip('\u2074' to '\u2079').toList
    for ((k, v) <- x) {
      tmp.update(k, v)
    }
    tmp.toMap
  }
  type ExponentTuple = (Int, String)

  def dealWithSign(s: String): ExponentTuple = {
    if (s.head == '+') {
      (1, s.tail.dropWhile(_ == '0'))
    } else if (s.head == '-') {
      (-1, s.tail.dropWhile(_ == '0'))
    } else {
      (1, s)
    }
  }

  def snBeautify(s: String): String = {
    val s1 = s.split("[Ee]").take(2)
    require(s1.length == 2)
    val coefficient = s1(0)
    val (sign, exponent) = dealWithSign(s1(1))
    val part1 = coefficient + '\u00d7' + "10"
    val part2 = exponent.map(superscriptMap(_))
    // if the number is negative, provide a superscript minus
    if (sign < 0) part1 + '\u207b' + part2
    else part1 + part2
  }

  def snBeautify1(s: String): String = {
    s.split("\\s").map(snBeautify(_)).mkString("\n")
  }

  def snBeautify(printOut: Boolean = true): Unit = {
    val toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit
    val clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard
    val s1 = clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor).asInstanceOf[String]
    val s2 = snBeautify1(s1)
    val s2Select = new StringSelection(s2)
    if (printOut) println(s2)
    clipboard.setContents(s2Select, s2Select)
  }
}

object Test1 {
  //  val s = List("4.2E+5", "4.2e5", "4.2e-5", "4.2E-5", "-4.2e-5")
  //  s.map(snBeautify(_))
  //  snBeautify1(s.mkString("\n"))
  //  val s1 = "1.74E-11\n2.72E-12\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n2.20E-11\n6.42E-12\n7.13E-11\n4.02E-11\n7.84E-12\n5.87E-12\n1.55E-11\n1.07E-10\n1.04E-10\n3.81E-11\n4.46E-11\n4.46E-11\n4.46E-11\n4.46E-11\n1.23E-10\n2.45E-11\n8.24E-12"
  //  snBeautify1(s1)
  // Copy the cells you want to reformat first
  Scientific.snBeautify()
}
```

Not a native Excel solution, but at least Scala is much nicer than VBA.

You can copy the cells you want to reformat and then run the `snBeautify` function, the reformatted numbers now sits in the clipboard ready for you to paste into Excel or Word.

One advantage of this solution is that it's equally applicable to LibreOffice or OpenOffice.

You can also easily modify this into a shell script and bind it to a certain keyboard shortcut.

Any suggestion for improvement of any kind is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is OK, it looks quite readable, but still some things may be cleaned a bit.

#### Encapsulation

Members are public by default, so some of them should be hidden, since they do not seem (and do not need) to be used from outside: `private val superscriptMap`, `private def dealWithSign`.

#### Don't Use Mutable Collections

Scala favors immutability and using things from `scala.collection.mutable` should be justified. There is a simple way here to bypass the mutability by concatenation of two maps:

```
private val superScriptImmutable = Map(
  '0' -> '\u2070',
  '1' -> '\u00b9',
  '2' -> '\u00b2',
  '3' -> '\u00b3'
) ++ ('4' to '9').zip('\u2074' to '\u2079').toMap
```

#### Use Matchers

`if.. else if.. else` are too much from imperative style; matchers should be used instead:

```
private def dealWithSign2(s: String): ExponentTuple = {
  def dropZeros(str : String) = str.dropWhile(_ == '0')
  s.head match {
    case '+' => (1, dropZeros(s.tail))
    case '-' => (-1, dropZeros(s.tail))
    case _ => (1, s)
  }
}
```

#### Misc

There should be a general check for input data that the args contain numbers. I've tried to pass "*test*" string to `snBeautify` and it returned `java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: s`, which is not explicit from the user's point of view.

`ExponentTuple` type does not seem to be used elsewhere except in the optional return type declaration in `dealWithSign` function. The type and the declaration can be removed without any harm.

In `snBeautify()` functions, `s1` and `s2` should be renamed according to their meaning, something like `original` and `beautified`. I'd also suggest to extract clipboard operations into dedicated functions, for example:

```
private def getFromClipboard = {
  val clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.getSystemClipboard
  clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor).asInstanceOf[String]
}
```